# Django translations of path **kwargs in urls.py?

Tags: django, internationalization, django-i18n

How can I translate the values passed to `**kwargs` within the `urls.py` file in Django, based on the language selected by the user? Translations in templates are working, and the language is determined by the `Accept-Language` header set by the Nginx server. However, this language selection doesn't have any effect within the `urls.py` file, and instead is determined by `LANGUAGE_CODE` in `settings.py` file.

Here is an example `urls.py`:

```
from django.urls import path
from main.views import SharedIndexView
from django.utils.translation import pgettext

app_name = 'some_site'

urlpatterns = [
    path('', SharedIndexView.as_view(), {'SITE_SEO_title':  pgettext('home', 'SITE_SEO_title')}
]
```

My question is, how can I translate the `**kwargs` values passed to the `path` method according to the user's selected language, and not according to `LANGUAGE_CODE`? Is there a different approach I could use to achieve this?

Comment: What if you use `pgettext_lazy`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The main problem is that `pgettext` is *eagerly*: it translates text when it is given that. So here when it interprets `urls.py` (for the first time), so *before* the moment the server starts accepting requests.

We need to *postpone* the translation process until we *need* the string, and thus then look for the language context. This is why `pgettext_lazy` is used:

```
from django.urls import path
from django.utils.translation import pgettext_lazy
from main.views import SharedIndexView

app_name = 'some_site'

urlpatterns = [
    path(
        '',
        SharedIndexView.as_view(),
        {'SITE_SEO_title': pgettext_lazy('home', 'SITE_SEO_title')},
    )
]
```

This will thus return an object that, when needed, translate the string.